# Does MS SQL Server Management Studio have a size limit associated with temp tables?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, ssms, temp-tables

I am running a large query that uses a 710-row temp table of PIDs.

Something like :

```
insert into #AdelText values /* these are my PIDs*/

('0YyGRz5sYOFlDtmRArU9'),
('f9982cdb-dcd8-4aed-b534-566b65963a09'),
('4db7a20d-7b47-494f-9397-a0e5df6c059d')
-- 700 MORE
('4db7a20d-7b47-494f-9397-a0e6c059d')
```

Well then I have to run a query on it that is a pivot like so( note that the PID here corresponds to the temp-table PIDs):

```
select * from

(

    select bis.SupplierID, bis.PID, rp.QuestionID,rp.Condition from  respondentprofiles RP (nolock)
    inner join BI_Sessions BIS (Nolock)
    on bis.RespondentID = rp.RespondentID
    inner join #adeltext at (nolock)
    on bis.pid = at.pid
    where 
     rp.QuestionID in 
        (
            51, 48  
        )
        and bis.surveyid = 14893 
)  

 as sourcetable 

PIVOT
(
    MAX(condition)
    for QuestionID in ([51],[48]) 
 )
PivotedTable
```

I expect to get 710 rows back, but I am getting 360 rows back. this is very puzzling to me. any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Are you sure that those questions on that survey have those 710 PIDs?. How many rows do you get when you do this?: `select DISTINCR bis.SupplierID, bis.PID FROM responde......`, without the `PIVOT`

Comment: @Lamak - this is avery good question. I ran that query, I get 598 rows . I'm a little confused now

Comment: I had changed the query before to simply say select distinct * from responde... and that got back over 1000 , whereas when I narrowed it down to the original columns it said 598

Comment: And the `DISTINCT` with just the columns `bis.SupplierID, bis.PID`?. I mean, you need the same filter ond joins that you are using on your `sourcetable`, only change the `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT bis.SupplierID, bis.PID`

Comment: Hmm, I need to study this a bit then . You're a step above me in skill here !

Comment: We can keep our conversation on this chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15476/discussion-between-lamak-and-adel